# Not able to connect android device over wifi with adb without a wire

Tags: android, adb, custom-rom

I was having trouble to connect my phone MI A2, unrooted, with custom rom of pixel experience android 13 to my pc(win 11) with adb over my wifi.
My charging C-Port broke due to some damage to my phone, so my phone doesn't take my data input or output from the port, but i am still able to charge my phone through it.

I have pixel experience android 13 version installed on my phone and with custom recovery of pixel experience.

I have tried going to my recovery and fastboot but my phone is still not being recognised.

I also tried to use the "pair with wifi" feature in android studio, version hedgehog, and it also doesn't seem to work.

Since no data is transferring through, my phone doesn't get recognised by my pc and I am not able to connect it through my wifi.

Somebody have any idea how can I connect my phone to my pc and access it.

EDIT:

I was able to connect my phone using "Pair with wifi" through android studios.

I don't know what happened but I reinstalled android studio hedgehog and was able to connect my through wifi using QR code(only for android 11+ phones).

Comment: Pair with WiFi is supposed to work, unless the developers of the custom ROM you use broke it. Therefore check your local network config if your PC can communicate to your phone on the WiFi interface.

Comment: Hi, make sure your firewall allows ADB connections and that USB debugging is enabled on your phone.